# AngularJS: Pass JSON embedded in HTML to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I embed search results directly into a HTML page to save a round trip. Currently I do the following:

```
<script>
  var embeddedResults = { /* rendered by server */ };

  var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
  app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.results = embeddedResults;
    // ...
  }]);
</script>
```

What is the proper way of doing this? Also: does this way allow me to put the `embeddedResults` variable at the very end of the page i.e., even after the controller definition?

Comment: Why do you want to put `embeddedResults` at the bottom of the page? If you are rendering from the server, I don't see a reason to do the assignment directly in the controller body e.g. `$scope.results = { /* rendered by server */ };`. If you want your controller to fully load before the results are assigned, you could use $timeout e.g. `$timeout(function() { $scope.results = { /* rendered by server */ }; })`

Comment: I want to inject the `results` array to be able to 1) test the controller more easily and 2) put the controller and `embeddedResults` variable into different files.

Comment: I'd just use a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 - global using $window

```
<script>
  var embeddedResults = { /* rendered by server */ };

  var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
  app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.results = $window.embeddedResults; // using $window will enable you to mock it in tests
    // ...
  }]);
</script>
```

Method 2 - constant/value

```
<script>  
  var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
  app.constant('embeddedResults', { /* rendered by server */ }); // can also be value
  app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "embeddedResults", function($scope, embeddedResults) {
    $scope.results = embeddedResults;
    // ...
  }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple service should give you what you are looking for:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('myService', function() {
    var person = { name: 'Arnold' }; //returned from the server

    this.getPerson = function(foo){
        return person;
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.person = myService.getPerson();
}
```